# create worker file (worker threads nodejs)

Tags: javascript, node.js, multithreading, worker-thread, node-worker-threads

I want to create a worker to send back an array as response to my main file, but I can't understand why the worker is not sending `postMessage` to main. Here is some dummy code to explain

My main file:

```
const { Worker } = require('worker_threads')
const worker = new Worker('./workerFile.js')

worker.on('message', msg => console.log(msg))
```

My workerFile.js

```
this.postMessage('hello world!')
```

Comment: With your code as it is, i'm getting
 [[node:internal/event_target:777
  process.nextTick(() => { throw err; });
                           ^
ReferenceError [Error]: parentPort is not defined ]]
Did it compile with you ?

Comment: It had an error, I apologize for my mistake, edited now.

Comment: So... It does work, with the fix, right ?

Comment: I had to import parentPort in the worker file as I wrote in the awnser.

Comment: Great :) Wasn't clear if your issue remained or not. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to import `parentPort` and then use it in workerFile.js:

```
const { parentPort } = require('worker_threads')
parentPort.postMessage('hello world!')
```